# Laplace Transform of $e^tu(-t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the Laplace Transform of $e^tu(-t)$.

We got $1/(s-1)$, and we know its wrong.

Comment: Yes, We have a signal that is x(t) = (e^(-t))(u(t)) + (e^(-t))(u(-t))

Comment: Note that 

$$\int_0^\infty e^t u(-t) e^{-st}\,dt=\int_0^0 e^t e^{-st}\,dt=0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^{-t}u(t) + e^{t}u(-t)=e^{-|t|} $$
It seems the question is about the two-sided LT  $\mathcal{L}(e^{-|t|})$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^tu(-t)e^{-st}dt=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{(1-s)t}dt=-\frac{1}{s-1}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t}u(t)e^{-st}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(s+1)t}dt=\frac{1}{s+1}$$

Therefore, $$\mathcal{L}(e^{-a|t|})=\frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{1}{s-1}=\frac{2}{1-s^2}$$